# how to add/update a new request param in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have a URL something like:

http://www.example.com/index.html?i=1&j=2&k=3.

I want to now create a new GET param which can hold the sum of all three GET params, say z is new GET Param which should be assigned value as 6. I want to use this new GET param z in another API call in my application later. 
How can I add/update existing GET request params array with this new GET param z and this new param should be available everywhere inside application ? I tried this but couldn't get working:

```
params[:z] = params[:i] + params[:j] + params[:k]
```

I am not able to read "z" anywhere in the application.

Comment: if u want to access it later also, then U can store it in the session.

Comment: I want to use params[:z] is another GET request so that could be another API call something like: http://www.example.com/next.html?z=6

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work around by using redirect_to with including your params[:z] value. You may use session to call your GET request later as Gopal rathore's suggestion.

Check it out: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to